# Spark Zepplin throws NPE on datasets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, apache-spark-dataset

I have been trying to run some experiments on datasets on zepplin 0.9 running locally. However I am running into NPEs when performing operations on Datasets. The same operations seem to work on Dataframe. Here is an example of what is failing

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

case class Person(firstname: String, middlename: String, lastname: String, id: String, gender: String, salary: Int)

val simpleData = Seq(Row("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    Row("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000),
    Row("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    Row("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    Row("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1)
  )

val simpleSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("firstname",StringType,true),
    StructField("middlename",StringType,true),
    StructField("lastname",StringType,true),
    StructField("id", StringType, true),
    StructField("gender", StringType, true),
    StructField("salary", IntegerType, true)
  ))

  val df = spark.createDataFrame(
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(simpleData),simpleSchema).as[Person]
  df.filter( x => x.firstname == "James").show()
```

This is the error that i get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.OuterScopes$$anonfun$getOuterScope$1.apply(OuterScopes.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.objects.NewInstance$$anonfun$10.apply(objects.scala:485)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.objects.NewInstance$$anonfun$10.apply(objects.scala:485)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.objects.NewInstance.doGenCode(objects.scala:485)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:105)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
```

Comment: No issue in a Databricks notebook. Spark 3.

Comment: 2.4.5 also no issue. But, DB is different to your place.

Comment: I get the impression zeppelin is problematic having googled around.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define Person case class in a different cell from use of as[Person]

#### cell 1

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

case class Person(firstname: String, middlename: String, lastname: String, id: String, gender: String, salary: Int)
```

#### cell2

```
val simpleData = Seq(Row("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    Row("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000),
    Row("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    Row("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    Row("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1)
  )

val simpleSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("firstname",StringType,true),
    StructField("middlename",StringType,true),
    StructField("lastname",StringType,true),
    StructField("id", StringType, true),
    StructField("gender", StringType, true),
    StructField("salary", IntegerType, true)
  ))

  val df = spark.createDataFrame(
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(simpleData),simpleSchema).as[Person]
  df.filter( x => x.firstname == "James").show()
```